# Command to find out -Xms and -Xmx variable values for a given java process?

Tags: java, jvm, java-opts

I have a java program, which i ran and figured out its process id with jps.

How can i see what is the value of -Xms and -Xmx variable for this java process ?

Comment: From you answer to SQL.injection's answer, it seems like you have a different `jps` on your Mac than I do. Can you add the following information to your question: (1) Which MacOS X version. (2) Which java version. (3) Results of running `which jps`. (4) Results of running `file $(which jps)`.

Comment: answers for questions :-  1) which jps - /usr/bin/jps 2) whic java version - java version "1.7.0_55" , 3) which MacOSX - 10.7.5 4) file $(which jps) -> /usr/bin/jps: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/bin/jps (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/jps (for architecture i386): Mach-O executable i386

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try

```
jcmd <PID> VM.command_line
jcmd <PID> VM.flags
```

Comment: the output gave me this - -XX:InitialHeapSize=1073741824 -XX:MaxHeapSize=17179869184 -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseParallelGC        Is It in Bytes . If the max heap size is in 17 GB , how is it even possible , because before running my program , my JAVA_OPTS was set as export JAVA_OPTS='-Xms128m -Xmx1024m' , it should not be more than 1 GB

Comment: @AdonSmith JVM itself does not recoginze `JAVA_OPTS`. Try `_JAVA_OPTIONS` instead.

Answer (score 8):

you can use jps and do it from the command line:

```
jps # shows pids
jps -v <pid> # shows params
jps -v <localhost:pid> # the host must be indicated
```

if this is not enough you can do it programmatically inside the program to check the [maximum amount of memory that the Java virtual machine will attempt to use](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#maxMemory()):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()
```

and you can also use use the class [MemoryUsage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryUsage.html) to get the initial, used and max ammount that can be used for memory management.

```
MemoryMXBean memoryBean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
    memoryBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getMax()
    memoryBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed()
    memoryBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getInit()
```

Comment: I am on mac OS 10.10 - when i typed the command jps -v <pid> , it failed- grep: 89038: No such file or directory

Comment: I don't want to do it programmatically . Need a command only :(

Comment: @AdonSmith you need to indicate the host. See again my awnser

Comment: i ran it -  jps -v localhost:89038, but it gave me an output - grep: localhost:89038: No such file or directory

Comment: @AdonSmith most likely there is no process id with that number.  I suggest just running `jps -lvm` without the id.

Comment: See i am running mac os, so may be your commands are not proper for that , can that be a reason ? because there is a processId , i found it by doing jps

Answer (score 6):

I think `jmap` command will give you everything you want.
usage: jmap -heap {pid}

```
root@BobServerStation:/usr/local $ jmap -heap 3280
Attaching to process ID 3280, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 24.65-b04

using thread-local object allocation.
Parallel GC with 8 thread(s)

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio = 0
   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 100
   MaxHeapSize      = 4116709376 (3926.0MB)
   NewSize          = 1310720 (1.25MB)
   MaxNewSize       = 17592186044415 MB
   OldSize          = 5439488 (5.1875MB)
   NewRatio         = 2
   SurvivorRatio    = 8
   PermSize         = 21757952 (20.75MB)
   MaxPermSize      = 85983232 (82.0MB)
   G1HeapRegionSize = 0 (0.0MB)

Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 65011712 (62.0MB)
   used     = 42273152 (40.3148193359375MB)
   free     = 22738560 (21.6851806640625MB)
   65.0239021547379% used
From Space:
   capacity = 10485760 (10.0MB)
   used     = 10479760 (9.994277954101562MB)
   free     = 6000 (0.0057220458984375MB)
   99.94277954101562% used
To Space:
   capacity = 10485760 (10.0MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 10485760 (10.0MB)
   0.0% used
PS Old Generation
   capacity = 171442176 (163.5MB)
   used     = 376368 (0.3589324951171875MB)
   free     = 171065808 (163.1410675048828MB)
   0.21953057805332568% used
PS Perm Generation
   capacity = 22020096 (21.0MB)
   used     = 15401488 (14.688003540039062MB)
   free     = 6618608 (6.3119964599609375MB)
   69.94287400018601% used

8464 interned Strings occupying 699456 bytes.
```

Comment: it gives me error : attach: task_for_pid(18830) failed (5)
Error attaching to process: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process

Comment: please use `sudo jmap -heap {pid}` @Adon Smith